# Which is faster Counter()+=Counter or Counter.update(Counter)?

Tags: python, function, profiling, counter, operator-keyword

**Which is faster?** `Counter()+=Counter` or `Counter.update(Counter)`?

**And why is one faster than the other?**

I've tried some simple profiling but i don't think it's enough to conclusively save that `Counter+=Counter` is faster than `Counter.update(Counter)`:

```
from collections import Counter
import time
x = Counter(['abc','def', 'abc'])
y = Counter(['xyz', 'xyz', 'uvw', 'abc'])

start = time.time()
x.update(y)
end = time.time() - start
print x
print 'update:', end
print 

x = Counter(['abc','def', 'abc'])
start = time.time()
x+=y
end = time.time() - start
print x
print 'plus:', end
```

[out]:

```
Counter({'abc': 3, 'xyz': 2, 'def': 1, 'uvw': 1})
update: 4.48226928711e-05

Counter({'abc': 3, 'xyz': 2, 'def': 1, 'uvw': 1})
plus: 2.28881835938e-05
```

Comment: Use `timeit` for microbenchmarks.

Comment: Note that there's a slight difference between those two methods: `update` changes x in-place, OTOH `+=` creates a new object and assigns it to `x`.(As no `__iadd__` method is present in `Counter` class. Source code: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py)

Comment: They added in-place operations in 3.3, though. [New in version 3.3: Added support for unary plus, unary minus, and in-place multiset operations.](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: @user2357112 I did add direct support an in-place operation in 3.3, but it is still slower than *update()* because *\_\_iadd\_\_()* has to do substantially more work to check-for and eliminate non-positive counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Counter.update()* method was designed to be faster.  The *__add__()* method does more work because it has to eliminate non-negative values:

```
# heart of the update() loop in Python 2:
for elem, count in iterable.iteritems():
    self[elem] = self_get(elem, 0) + count

# heart of the __add__() loop in Python 2:
result = Counter()
for elem, count in self.items():
    newcount = count + other[elem]
    if newcount > 0:
        result[elem] = newcount
for elem, count in other.items():
    if elem not in self and count > 0:
        result[elem] = count
return result
```

As you can see, the *__add__* method does considerable more work.

There is another difference in later versions of Python 3 which have an *__iadd__()* method that does a true in-place update that does less work than an *__add__()* method which creates a new counter followed by an assignment to replace the old counter:

```
def __iadd__(self, other):
    for elem, count in other.items():
        self[elem] += count
    return self._keep_positive()
```